# Which of the following has the greatest value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, exponentiation

Which of the following has the greatest value?

a) $2^{64}$  b) $4^{63}$  c) $8^{34}$  d) $16^{17}$

I tried finding a pattern among exponents and their is none. but there is a pattern in base, but I'm unable to find the common power through which I'll compare the base and figure the answer. What is the best possible option to solve this question within 1.5 minutes?

Comment: Express all of them as exponents of two

Comment: There's a very clear pattern in the bases: $4 = 2^2$, for a start.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

- $16^{17}=\left(2^4\right)^{17}=2^{4\times17}=2^{68}$

and similarly for the other powers of $2$

Comment: Ohh I got it, It was so right in the front, I was being stupid. Thank you so much. Correct answer is B right?

Comment: Can you please help me with this question as well? I'm stuck and not getting any replies https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019103/calculating-change-in-percentage

Comment: @shawn k I’ve answered your question.

Comment: @KM101 Thanks a-lot!!! Really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $$16^{17}=4^{34}<4^{63}\\2^{64}=4^{32}<4^{63}\\8^{34}=4^{34\times {3\over 2}}=4^{51}<4^{63}$$ therefore $4^{63}$ has the greatest value among all.